# Finding the button control click in wpf data grid SelectionChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

My data grid cod e is as below

```
        <my:DataGrid Name="dgSupplierList" SelectionMode="Single"   CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False"   
                 Margin="10,10,10,10"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" GridLinesVisibility="All" Background="Transparent"
                 RowHeight="23" RowBackground="White" AlternatingRowBackground="AliceBlue" SelectionUnit="FullRow" ColumnHeaderHeight="25"
                 OverridesDefaultStyle="True"  SelectionChanged="dgSupplierList_SelectionChanged" Grid.Row="1">
            <my:DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="my:DataGridRow">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </my:DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <my:DataGrid.Columns>
                <my:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SupplierId}" Header="Supplier ID"  Visibility="Hidden" ></my:DataGridTextColumn>
                <my:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FullName}" Header="Organization" Width="225" IsReadOnly="True"></my:DataGridTextColumn>
                <my:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ChartName}" Header="Chart Name" Width="150" IsReadOnly="True"></my:DataGridTextColumn>
                <my:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ORG_ID}" Header="ID" Width="50" IsReadOnly="True"></my:DataGridTextColumn>
                <my:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Country}" Header="Country" Width="125" IsReadOnly="True"></my:DataGridTextColumn>
                <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="AddStakeholders" Width="100" Header="Add Stakeholders" CanUserResize="False">
                    <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent"   Height="25" Tag="{Binding SupplierId}" CommandParameter="{Binding SupplierId}"   Name="btnAdd" Click="btnAdd_Click" >
                                <Image    Stretch="Uniform"  Margin="0,0,0,0"  Source="/ADES;component/Images/addimage.jpg"   />
                            </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </my:DataGrid.Columns>

        </my:DataGrid>
```

When button btnAdd is clicked it calls code behind method btnAdd_Click . But since the button in data grid , before executing btnAdd_Click method , dgSupplierList_SelectionChanged is executed . I want to skip the  execution of the code block of dgSupplierList_SelectionChanged if btnAdd is clicked . How can I do this ?

How can i check whether it is click of btnAdd control  inside dgSupplierList_SelectionChanged   so that i can skip the code in it .?

Comment: try to get control at mouse coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of hacks :

1. remove Click event, in your OnSelectionChanged you travel the visual tree to see the type diff from TextBlock and the Button, 
   if it's a Button, do your special logic there.
2. add in DataGrid Mouse.PreviewMouseDown="OnPreviewMouseDown" ...
   that'll fire before the Click or SelectionChanged...so you can add your logic there.
3. Cleaner would be to bind:

   DataGrid's SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem}"

   Button's Command="{Binding Command}"

   That way both get set regardless in your ViewModel, or code behind where you can say, hay if my selected items is such, I am not going to execute the command

Answer (score 0):

Your answer actually worked for me but I can't uptick it because of stack overflows merit rules :-).  The problem I had is that I had to hit the button twice to get it to fire the command.  Once for row selection, once for a button press.

Normally I would just bind the command inside the data grid and it would work,

```
   <Button  Style="{StaticResource LinkButton}" Content="Remove" Command="{Binding DataContext.RemoveCommand, Source={StaticResource ProxyElement}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
```

But as above, that didn't work.

Here is what I had to do.

```
 <Button PreviewMouseDown="UIElement_OnPreviewMouseDown" Style="{StaticResource   LinkButton}" Content="Remove" />

  private void UIElement_OnPreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    ViewModel.RemoveCommand.Execute(((sender as Button).DataContext));
  }
```

This did the trick inside the datagrid, but it is of course, not a great MVVM solution and hurts me to even have to do it.  I'm using WPF 3.5, so perhaps MS fixed this issue in WPF 4.0.